# Trying to add background image in html and css behind the nav bar so space doesn't show when scrolling

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out how to make the background image in my html and css to fill under the navbar and footer. When I scroll the space of the navbar is just a white space, I want it to scroll without space at the top and bottom. Thanks!

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
  body, html {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

.background-container {
  background-image: url("http://placekitten.com/g/500/500");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: -1;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


.logo-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 30%; /* Adjust the height as needed */
}

.logo-container img{
  max-width: auto;
  max-height: 600px;
  text-align: center;


}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  /* Adjust background image for mobile devices */
  .background-container {
    background-position: center;
    height: auto;
  }
}

.footer {
  padding: 25px 0;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}


@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .logo-container {
    margin-top: 50px;
  }


  .footer {
    position: relative;
  }
  .navbar {
      position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">The Backyard</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#events">Events</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="background-container"></div>
  <div class="logo-container">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/100/100" alt="Logo">
    </div>

<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <p>The Backyard<br>
      at Boca Fiesta & Palomino<br>
      232 1/2 SE 1st st.<br>
      Gainesville, FL 32601</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

I've tried to change the code on both css and html but nothing seems to be changing the result.

Comment: that was accidental! so sorry for the confusion, I couldn't tell in the photo preview.

Comment: fixed it and pasted the code :)

Comment: Why are you including Bootstrap 4 CSS and 3 JS?

Comment: The only background image I see is for "background-container", which is after the nav and before the footer. If you want the background image to be behind everything, then apply it to body

Comment: I've turned your code into a snippet that can be run in your question, and I replaced your image links with cat pictures since the images linked to don't exist for us here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you have created a new element that you are putting the BG image on instead of just putting it on the `<body>` tag, but your problem is because at small screen sizes you are setting `height:auto` on the `.background-container` element.

You have created an element, made it fixed position and then made it 100% tall, 100% wide.  When the screen size is small and you set `height:auto` now that element has a height of `0px` since there's nothing inside that element.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
  body, html {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

.background-container {
  background-image: url("http://placekitten.com/g/500/500");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: -1;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


.logo-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 30%; /* Adjust the height as needed */
}

.logo-container img{
  max-width: auto;
  max-height: 600px;
  text-align: center;


}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  /* Adjust background image for mobile devices */
  .background-container {
    background-position: center;
    /*height: auto;*/    /* <=======  REMOVE THIS */
  }
}

.footer {
  padding: 25px 0;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}


@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .logo-container {
    margin-top: 50px;
  }


  .footer {
    position: relative;
  }
  .navbar {
      position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">The Backyard</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#events">Events</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="background-container"></div>
  <div class="logo-container">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/100/100" alt="Logo">
    </div>

<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <p>The Backyard<br>
      at Boca Fiesta & Palomino<br>
      232 1/2 SE 1st st.<br>
      Gainesville, FL 32601</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Also you are including Bootstrap 4 CSS and Bootstrap 3 JS - this makes no sense at all.  Pick one of the other, you can't mix versions like this!

Comment: thank you so such for your time! I was trying things out to see the web page response and stupidly overlooked this

Answer (score 0):

I suggested in a comment on your question to apply the background image to `body`, but I can't think of how you would apply opacity in that manner. So, just move `<div class="background-container"></div>` to the top of the page.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
  body, html {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

.background-container {
  background-image: url("http://placekitten.com/g/500/500");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: -1;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


.logo-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 30%; /* Adjust the height as needed */
}

.logo-container img{
  max-width: auto;
  max-height: 600px;
  text-align: center;


}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  /* Adjust background image for mobile devices */
  .background-container {
    background-position: center;
    height: auto;
  }
}

.footer {
  padding: 25px 0;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}


@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .logo-container {
    margin-top: 50px;
  }


  .footer {
    position: relative;
  }
  .navbar {
      position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="background-container"></div>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">The Backyard</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#events">Events</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

  <div class="logo-container">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/100/100" alt="Logo">
    </div>

<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <p>The Backyard<br>
      at Boca Fiesta & Palomino<br>
      232 1/2 SE 1st st.<br>
      Gainesville, FL 32601</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```